# How to use Razor like asp:Literal?

Tags: tags, razor

I have a simple Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public string Text{get;set;}
}
```

I have a View, which renders Text property of MyModel:

```
<p>@Model.Text</p>
```

How can I render html tags from Text like tags? For example, I have Text "`<b>Text</b>`". I want to get bold text inside tag p as result:

**Text**

But Razor renders text as is:

```
<b>Text</b>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you need to use it like:

```
<p>@Html.Raw(Model.Text)</p>
```

You can find more info [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) on Phil Haack's blog.

[anurse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29813/anurse) points out in the comments that you could, alternatively, set the type of the `Text` member of your View Model type as `IHtmlString` and just use `@Model.Text` to output it. ASP.NET MVC is clever enough to realize that the output should not be escaped.

Comment: This is a good solution when you want to render some content without HTML encoding occasionally. When you _know_ that a property of your model is always going to be HTML content that shouldn't be automatically encoded, you should make the type of that property IHtmlString. So if you change Text to be an IHtmlString instead of a string, you can type @Model.Text and Razor will output the tags properly. That way, it's clear that certain content is HTML and should be carefully sanitized to avoid HTML Injection Attacks.

Comment: @anurse: Wow, great comment. Didn't know that myself. I will update the answer to add this information as well.